# Android Setting id parameter for linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add some views programatically to a linear layout which is already defined in the xml file.

This is my code for defining the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

However, as you can see it does not have an id element. How can I add one so that I can call the method findViewById from my activity to retrieve the layout? I tried adding it manually but it is not generated in the R.java.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, like this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
```

If you add it and have an issue, try Project -> Clean.

If all else fails, find and nuke the R.java file in your gen -> package directory to force a rebuild of it.